How to switch camera while recording video with camera package in Flutter?
I can switch between the front and back cameras if I'm not recording video. But while recording video the camera preview widget goes black for a short while and then shows the same camera, not switching to the new camera.
I'm working with Flutter 3.24.3 and Camera package 0.11.0+2.
Future<void> switchCamera() async {
    if (cameraController != null) {
      final lensDirection = cameraController!.description.lensDirection;
      CameraDescription newDescription;
      if (lensDirection == CameraLensDirection.front) {
        newDescription = cameras.firstWhere((description) => description.lensDirection == CameraLensDirection.back);
      } else {
        newDescription = cameras.firstWhere((description) => description.lensDirection == CameraLensDirection.front);
      }
      await cameraController!.setDescription(newDescription);
    } else {
      await _initializeCameraController(_getDefaultCamera());
    }
  }

If you have encountered this error please let me know the solution.
Any help is always appreciated.

You must stop the video recording when switching the camera, then reinitialize the camera with the desired lens and start recording again.
The camera package does not yet support hot-switching cameras mid-recording without stopping and restarting.

Thanks!
I see in the documentation that it allows the camera to be switched while video recording since version 0.10.4.
Do we still need to pause recording and resume recording?

yes , i think so

If I reinitialize the camera controller, the current recording session will be closed, I cannot call resumeVideoRecording anymore.

Iam Really sorry for that , But in documentation This only is given
